# How to rephrase "What kind of me will make you miss"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I'm trying to phrase the following sentence in question form: "what kind, in what form of myself would make you miss me".
This is what I figured out:

> What kind of me will make you miss?

Close enough, but it looks awkward. How can I rephrase this?

Comment: You're probably trying to ask, "What would you miss about me?" The preposition **about** can be used to describe a quality apparent in a person. [Definition 3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what @JamesK says in his answer, but I think it is perfectly possible for different me's to exist over time or in parallel. In fact, it's not such an uncommon concept in psychology and literature. ([Some examples here](https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22there%20are%20different%20me%27s%22))

I think it is correct to say:

*Which **me** would you miss the most?*

(The never-give-up me? The sulky-and-moody me? The early-riser me? The dashing-and-daring me you fell in love with? The laconic-but-affable me I later became?)

Comment: I think your suggestion is closer. Can I rephrase it like this: "What kind of me would you miss the most?" (I think I've figured out this combination once, I just don't remember clearly, it was 4 years ago...)

Comment: In my answer I tired to remain as true as possible to what I assumed you had in mind. However, I think @OldBrixtonian's suggestion is the most common and natural way of putting it, and it does have the idea of the different aspects/qualities embedded in it. "What would you miss the most about me?" "Yours eyes / Your maddening optimism / ..."

Comment: "What kind of me" sounds very odd to a native speaker. "What aspect of me", "What... about me" or "Which 'me'" would all be preferable.

Comment: * "Your" eyes, obviously... :-(

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is problematic in several ways.

The verb "miss" in this sense is transitive. It has a direct object.  If you use it without an object it has the sense of "miss (a target)"

The notion that there are different "kinds of me" is odd.  This may be cultural, but "me" is just "me", and there is only one kind.  I may have different roles, but I am just one individual. So the phrase "What kind of me" is very odd.

The "make you miss (me)" part is also odd, as it seems to suggest that you intend to make someone unhappy.

So, I'm afraid this whole sentence needs to be thrown away.  Old Brixtonian has a much better suggestion.  "What would you miss about me?"

Comment: I get the point that "me is just me." But I think what I was trying to say "If there's a moment that you miss me, what am I look like?"

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of "how will you remember me?"